# Prevent duplicates due to multiple values in right table during left join

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables.

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

After doing left join , I get the resultant as

Resultant table

[image]

Since there are duplicate values in table 2 i get extra rows after left join. How can I avoid these duplicate values during left join?

Desired Output

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: How about using DISTINCT? (`SELECT DISTINCT ...`)

Comment: There are multiple ways you could do this.  It's impossible to know what the right one is without knowing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please don't post images -- post text instead.  We cannot copy/paste for testing.

Comment: Also, please show us what you have done so far.  It is confusing that you say Table 2 has duplicates -- from what little you've posted Table 2 looks like it would be a customer table where customer id would be the primary key, and thus not possible to have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68065/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (CustomerID int,ItemID int,QTY int)
CREATE TABLE Table2 (CustomerID int,Customer varchar(255))
INSERT INTO Table1 (CustomerID,ItemID,QTY)VALUES(1234,1,2),
                                                (1235,2,3),
                                                (1236,3,5),
                                                (1237,4,7)

INSERT INTO Table2(CustomerID,Customer)VALUES(1234,'ABC'),
                                             (1235,'XYZ'),
                                             (1234,'ABC'),
                                             (1236,'MNO'),
                                             (1237,'MNM'),
                                             (1235,'XYZ')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.CustomerID,T1.ItemID,T1.QTY,T2.Customer
FROM Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.CustomerID=T2.CustomerID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68065/1/0)**:

```
| CustomerID | ItemID | QTY | Customer |
|------------|--------|-----|----------|
|       1234 |      1 |   2 |      ABC |
|       1235 |      2 |   3 |      XYZ |
|       1236 |      3 |   5 |      MNO |
|       1237 |      4 |   7 |      MNM |
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have multiple values for the same customer ID in table 1?

Comment: @vicky You tell us.  What do you want to do if there are multiple values for the same customer ID in table 1?  Sum them?  Take the maximum?  Show all the values?  I'm guessing you're going for aggregation here somewhere, but you need to provide sufficient information for us to help you.